# 64 cores are detected, but more jobs can run in parallel

Tags: r, linux, parallel-processing, job-scheduling, cpu-cores

In the node where I do parallel computing, I get

```
parallel::detectCores()
[1] 64
```

However, when I run my job that runs 120 parallel sub-jobs at once, it starts working! In other words, it assigns 120 workers, saying these messages;

```
starting worker pid=22473 on localhost:11962 at 15:59:09.328
starting worker pid=22482 on localhost:11962 at 15:59:09.611
starting worker pid=22491 on localhost:11962 at 15:59:09.892
starting worker pid=22500 on localhost:11962 at 15:59:10.172
...
```

(I didn't post all 120 lines due to space)

**I don't get it why it is running well. Could you let me know what I am missing?
How can I know the maximum number of jobs I can submit?**

---

I'm using

- Linux

`$ lsb_release -a` gives me this;

```
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
Release:    6.9
Codename:   Final
```

- R 3.4.3

Please let me know if you need more information.

---

The example code would be like;

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
n_cluster <- 120
cl <- makeCluster(n_cluster, outfile = "./out.txt")
cat(sprintf("---------------------------------\n"))
cat(sprintf("No. of clusters registered = %d\n", n_cluster))
cat(sprintf("---------------------------------\n"))
registerDoParallel(cl)
res_fit <- foreach(i = 1:n_cluster) %dopar% {
  cat(sprintf("i=%d\n", i))
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: from manual pages: detectCores(all.tests = FALSE, logical = TRUE), logical  

Logical: if possible, use the number of physical CPUs/cores (if FALSE) or logical CPUs (if TRUE). Currently this is honoured only on macOS, Solaris and Windows. So to me it is that's only considering your physical cpus

Comment: `detectCores` does not in itself limit how many sub-processes may be started, it only informs you or whatever code you are using to start your cluster of R processes. Just because you have 64 cores (impressive) does not mean you cannot start 65 or 129 or 2000 processes, it only informs you so that you do not over-obligate computer resources. (Starting more processes than cores might be ok but in many circumstances is not good practice.)

Comment: do you know how many threads you've got?  lscpu | grep -E '^Thread|^Core|^Socket|^CPU\('

Comment: @Hack-R I updated my post with an example.

Comment: @r2evans That's something very new to me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ElioDiaz Thanks for asking! Thread (2) / Core (8) / Socket (4) / CPU (64)

Comment: that means 2 threads x 64 cores; so as i stated before, detectCores doesn't give you the number of logical cpus in linux, that's why you get 64 cores

Comment: @r2evans I have one more question if you don't mind. Why is it possible to start more processes than # of cores? Doesn't it take one core to run a single rcode?

Comment: Have you ever looked at the list of processes/applications running on a system? I have a 4-core surface book running win10_64, and Task Manager reports 10 apps, 86 background processes, and 108 windows processes, and that's not counting threads within. On a nearby linux 8-core workstation, there are 205 processes listed by `ps fax`. You can most definitely have more processes than cores, with the assumption that most of them are in some form of "waiting state", waiting for disk i/o, waiting for network i/o, waiting for user i/o, waiting for ... some time to pass.

Comment: How many cores should you allot? That depends. If your code is fairly CPU-intensive, then I would assume no more than 1 core per "rcode process", and depending on the computer itself, you might want to go with "n-cores minus 1" so that your system processes have some "wiggle room". If your code is more forgiving, perhaps you can go with 2-to-1 or more. A usable metric (on \*nix-like machines) is `/proc/loadavg`, where a number under either 1x or 2x the number of cores (depending on your personality and risk aversion) is an acceptable load.

Comment: ... and this says nothing about other resources you may need. For instance, if one rcode process uses 1/3 of your available RAM, then you most certainly should go with no more than 2 at a time, as [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)) is generally a "Bad Thing (tm)".

Comment: So an easier question to answer is *"when have I gone too far?"* You'll know you've gone too far when your computer just reboots (best case), freezes (hard to know if it's locked or just under-responsive), or worst-case you can hear the spindle hard drives clicking as the heads crash due to VM paging. Try "a few", and monitor your computer resources; on windows, look at the "Performance" tab of Task Manager, specifically at CPU utilization and Memory. Under \*nix, `top` or `htop` are good starts. If it looks like things are flowing easily, try one more next time.

Comment: Setting an R cluster to more cores than you have is like writing a check larger than your monthly paycheck: if they wait the week or so for your next payday to cash it, then you'll be fine, but if they cash it right away, you're in a world of overdraft. You can write a check as big as you want, but it's a matter of the state-of-your-account when it is cashed. With one of my large-scale processes (64-1000 cores), I tend to stagger starting the individual processes so that they don't all "peak" at the same time. It works here, but not everywhere.

Comment: @r2evans I do appreciate your kind and detailed answer for a novice like me. It comes to my mind that I've seen many processors running in the system. Thanks again.

Comment: Hope it helps you resolve your dilemma.